# How do I Authenticate and get tokens for ASP .NET CORE WEB API Application With On-Premisis ADFS?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, adfs, bearer-token, adfs4.0

I am having a web application which is using ADFS for authentication this application is done in .net framework. I have written services in ASP.NET Core as of now there is no authentication for web api requests i want to to add ADFS authentication to web api how can i access this web api? how do i talk to this api after configuring it to adfs? what is the best way to access web api as they both were ADFS applications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I setup a valid on-premise ADFS URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961921/how-do-i-setup-a-valid-on-premise-adfs-uri)

Answer (score 0):

To issue the token for the web API, we need to make the ADFS to aware it by creating a relying party trust for the web API. And when we add a replying party we need to specify the identifiers for the replying party:

And then we can use this identifiers as the reosurce URI to acquire the token for this replying party.

Please ensure that the resource URI is correct as you config.

here is a very nice article about developing with ADFS using OAuth:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx

Check this thread too

https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-WS-Federation

Hope it helps.