# How to get token from ADFS Server without using ADFS Login Page only by sending Username and password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jwt, adfs, adal

I want to fetch token from on-premisis ADFS Server how can i get the token by passing client credentials rather than redirecting to ADFS Login Page and getting token.

Comment: I think you need to configure a redirect URL to get this token? this will make it possible not to prompt/show a page but allows you to fetch the token by QueryString=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961921/how-do-i-setup-a-valid-on-premise-adfs-uri

Comment: When you say client credentials, do you mean the application credentials or a user's credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the reply here i mean user credentials

Answer (score 0):

Depending on @SamuelsD's answer, you can either use the OAuth "client credentials" flow (refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs)) or the OAuth "resource owner password" flow (refer [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicold/2018/03/23/oauth-2-0-protocol-support-level-for-adfs-2012r2-vs-adfs-2016/)).

The resource owner password flow is deprecated these days as it is not considered to be secure.