# Integrate ADFS with Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, oauth, saml, adfs, adal

I have to integrate [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) with angular 2 Project. I know, this ADFS is old one now. But We need this only.

I found similar question
[On-Prem ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37568725/2810015) . It suggests to use [angular2-adal](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal). I have tried that Also.
But this thing is giving me the ADFS error Page, when clicking on login button.
Below is the code, which I am trying.

```
private endpoints: any = {
    'http://localhost:58689':
          'https://localhost:44302', // as registered in ADFS //  
  };


  public get adalConfig(): any {
    return {
        instance: 'https://adfs.domain.com/',
        tenant: 'adfs', 
        clientId: 'https://localhost:44302',  
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
        endpoints: this.endpoints
    };
  }
```

I do not know, what is the error, I have tried many combinations to set the properties, But always the same error page.

Note:

1. `http://localhost:58689` is my local website URl
2. https://localhost:44302   // is Relying party identifier On ADFS Server.

Questions:

1) Is it necessary that my site should be on https, It can be on HTTP also,

2) Is there any alternate solution apart from `angular2-adal`, for ADFs integration with Angular 2, I need only ADFS.this is the only problem (No OAuth, No SAML)

Answer (score 0):

In order to talk to ADFS, you **have** to use OpenID Connect (OAuth), WS-Fed or SAML.

You also need ADFS 4.0.

Yes - you need to use ADAL.

Here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs).